# C: Pointer to a structure element

Tags: c

I tried to read on it from past questions and watch youtube videos but i don't get it.

I have a program with struct called info. I created a function that adds element of the structure and return a pointer to it.
then i want to use the element fields through the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Info {
    char* name;
    char type;
    char* path;
};

struct Info* AddInfo(char* input);
int main(void) {

    char input[128];

    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    struct info *Puser;
    Puser=malloc(sizeof(AddInfo(input)));
    &Puser=AddInfo(input);
    //here is my problem. 
    return 0;
}

struct Info *AddInfo( char* input) {
    struct Info user1;
    struct info* Puser=0;
    char *s;

    //assign to name
    for (int i = strlen(input) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (input[i] == '/') {

            s = malloc(sizeof(input));
            strncpy(s, input + i + 1, i);

            user1.name = malloc(sizeof(s));
            if (user1.name == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in malloc");
            }

            strcpy(user1.name, s);
            user1.name[i] = '\0';
            free(s);
            break;
        }
    }
    //assign to type
    if ((user1.type = malloc(sizeof(user1.type)) == NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in malloc");
    }
    if (input[strlen(input) - 1] == '/') {
        user1.type = 'd';
    } else {
        user1.type = 'f';
    }
    //assign to path
    user1.path = malloc(sizeof(input));

    if (user1.path == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in malloc");
    }
    strcpy(user1.path, input);

    // printf("%s \n", user1.path);
    // printf("%s\n", user1.name);
    // free(user1.name);

    Puser= &user1;

    return Puser;
}
```

How should i do that correctly ? how can i take user1 and access it through pointer outside the function ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The word you are looking for is `malloc`.

Comment: I did Puser=malloc(sizeof(AddInfo(input))); or i'm not sure where you mean

Comment: `struct Info` is not the same as `struct info`.

Comment: @erans: That is related to `user1` how?

Comment: @ScottHunter you mean i have to do user1=malloc(sizeof(struct)) in the beginning of the function?

Comment: @dbush thanks i didn't see that :O

Comment: Note that `sizeof(AddInfo(input))` is equivalent to `sizeof(struct Info *)` (that is, evaluating `sizeof` does not involve calling the function), and that the size of a pointer is completely independent of the size of the thing to which it points.

Answer (score 1):

Your function AddUser assigns all the data to a function-local variable then returns a pointer to that data, but as soon as the function returns that local is no longer valid, you need to allocate the new Info in AddUser rather than main and assign the data to that allocated instance and return that pointer.

```
typedef struct Info {
    char * name;
    ...
} Info;

Info * AddUser(char const * name);

int main()
{
    Info * pNewUser = AddUser("Bob");
    ...
    free(pNewUser);
    return 0;

}

Info AddUser(char const * name)
{
    if(!name || !*name)
        return NULL;

    Info * pNew = malloc(sizeof(Info));
    if(!pNew)
        return NULL;

    size_t len = strlen(name);
    pNew->name = malloc(len+1);
    if(!pNew->name)
    {
        free(pNew);
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(pNew->name, name);
    return pNew;
}
```

Comment: I understood what you wrote before the code. but i can't understand the code itself. I see another function of Adduser that initialize the name. anywhere i can read on pointers and local variables in functions ? Thanks for you help